# HttpConnectionUrl always return status code 307

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, httpconnection

I am trying to hit a web service. it is working fine with android 4.4 or android 5.X. but when i am trying to hit "`http://inmotion-prod.cloudapp.net:145/service1.svc/json/GetCustomerUUID"` using android 4.1.1 it always returning me 307 status code. but this url is working fine with android 4.4 or 5.x. i also tried to hit other url it is working fine on android 4.1.1. 
so please tell me what is the problem

```
Log.i(TAG, url);
        String response = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL webServiceUrl = new URL(url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) webServiceUrl
                    .openConnection();
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection open");
            conn.setRequestMethod(GET);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
            conn.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
            conn.setRequestProperty(ACCEPT_TYPE, acceptType);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection Connected");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && conn.getInputStream() != null) {
                response = StreamUtility.convertStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());
                conn.getInputStream().close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: This is happening because of headers check your code once here:- conn.setRequestProperty(TOKEN, header); Make sure whatever you are passing to webservices confirmed in API client

Comment: i am not passing any header here

Comment: Dude, All the set operations for "conn" are treated as header. First, Check your webservice in REST API client & then implement code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your URL address with `http://inmotion-prod.cloudapp.net:145/service1.svc/json/GetCustomerUUID/` (pay attention to `/` at the end). The response code will be `200`.

---

**UPDATE:**

With your current URL address (`http://inmotion-prod.cloudapp.net:145/service1.svc/json/GetCustomerUUID`) without `/` at the end, you can use the following code:

```
String address = "http://inmotion-prod.cloudapp.net:145/service1.svc/json/GetCustomerUUID";
URL url = new URL(address);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
// if print out (debug or logging), you will see secondURL has / at the end
URL secondURL = new URL(urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location"));
HttpURLConnection urlConnection1 = (HttpURLConnection) secondURL.openConnection();
```

Then use `urlConnection1.getResponseCode()`

Hope it helps!

Comment: A really annoying behavior (bug?). Thanks for this code. Works great

Answer (score 0):

BNK's answer helped, I fixed it like this so that it also works on newer devices (location header was returned as null / empty!)

```
String headerLocation = httpsUrlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
logger.debug("Location header: " + headerLocation);

// if the redirect URL ends with a "/" sign, but the original URL does not, it's probably the redirect bug
String originalURL = url.toString();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(headerLocation) && headerLocation.endsWith("/") && !originalURL.endsWith("/"))
    {
    logger.info("Redirect Location differs from original URL, create new connection to: " + headerLocation);
    httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(headerLocation).openConnection();

    // optional
    httpsUrlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    }
```